# How to consolidate data of Specific columns from multiple sheet to one sheet using excel macro when the required columns are not in same order

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, excel-2010

I have defects for different project in an excel sheet with 10 project sheets e.g sheet A, Sheet B Sheet C ,Sheet D ,sheet E,Sheet F etc

Each sheet has different columns, **Defect id, defect summary, severity, priority, reported by, assigned to, status, date** etc

I want following columns (which is **NOT IN SAME ORDER in all sheets**) from all sheets to one sheet(defectconsolidation)

**Defect id,Defect summary,severity,priority and status**

When clicked a button , I need to see all above fields from **JUST A,B and C project sheet and not from  all project.**

hope some one will help.

**Note**: I can copy paste it manually but the requirement is we need to have a macro 
so far just created a excel sheet with name "defect consolidation" in my workbook
thats all :( am bit new to macro

system details : windows 7 and microsoft offer 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does as I interpreted your question. This should provide you a starting point if your requirements are a little different.

Attach the following code to your button ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub consolidate()
    Dim myInSht As Worksheet
    Dim myOutSht As Worksheet
    Dim aRow As Range
    Dim aCol As Range
    Dim myInCol As Range
    Dim myOutCol As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long

    jLoop = 2

' loop through the worksheets
    For Each myInSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
' pick only the worksheets of interest
        If myInSht.Name = "PrjA" Or myInSht.Name = "PrjB" Or myInSht.Name = "PrjC" Then
' find the columns of interest in the worksheet
            For Each aCol In myInSht.UsedRange.Columns
                Set myOutCol = Nothing
                If aCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Defect id" Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A:A")
                If aCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Defect summary" Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("B:B")
                If aCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = "severity" Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("C:C")
                If aCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = "priority" Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("D:D")
                If aCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = "status" Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("E:E")

                If Not myOutCol Is Nothing Then
' don't move the top line, it contains the headers - no data
                    Set myInCol = aCol
                    Set myInCol = myInCol.Offset(1, 0).Resize(myInCol.Rows.Count - 1, myInCol.Columns.Count)
' transfer data from the project tab to the consolidated tab
                    iLoop = jLoop
                    For Each aRow In myInCol.Rows
                        myOutCol.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value = aRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
                        iLoop = iLoop + 1
                    Next aRow
                End If
            Next aCol
        End If
        If iLoop > jLoop Then jLoop = iLoop
    Next myInSht
End Sub
```

I used the following to test ...
The consolidated tab before consolidation ...
[image]

Project A contents ...

[image]

Project B contents ...

[image]

Project C contents ...

[image]

And after running the consolidation routine ...

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how to mark it, sorry i am very new here...thanks in advance.

Comment: @OldUgle can i give multiple conditions like this with OR i have a same field  of values but name is different  ?                                If aCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Defect ID" Or "Key" Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A:A")

Comment: Did you try? OR, AND and NOT are all valid in IF THEN logic.

Comment: yeah tried, it was throwing error. in my excel workbook , i have defects in multiple sheets with different headings. , if i could concatenate wtih OR it should pick value as and when it finds it

Comment: Sorry, I see the syntax error now. `If (aCol.Cells(1,1).Value = "Defect ID") Or (aCol.Cells(1,1).Value = "Key") Then Set myOutCol = Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A:A")`

Comment: cool... :) you are the best :) i will take a class from you :)

Comment: i need one more request from above your 
in Consolidation sheet I need all Sheet name in A column left of defect 
ex

Proj      Defect
Prj A       123-A456 
Prj A     123-A457
Prj A     123-A458
Prj B    123-A459
Prj C   123-A460
Prj C  123-A461

Comment: this worked,thanks you

  For Each aRow In myInCol.Rows
  myOutCol.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value = aRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
 Cells(iLoop, 1).Value = myInSht.Name
     iLoop = iLoop + 1
      Next aRow

Comment: would you be able to help me here? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684741/how-to-find-mulitiple-duplicate-values-in-excel-column-and-consolidate-the-dupli/36688184#36688184