# How to find multiple duplicate values in Excel column and consolidate the duplicated for a specific value using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement,
I have an Excel with values JIRA ID, Defect ID, Duplicate ID, Duplicate

-In JIRA ID column I have all ALM defect ids which has linked JIRA IDs marked.

-I need to take all ALM id which has JIRA ID marked on JIRA ID Column.

-put it against respective JIRA ID on Duplicated ID column separated with (,).

-mark the JIRA id as duplicate

#### list the duplicate ALM values corresponding JIRA id in Excel using macro

[image: list the duplicate ALM values corresponding JIRA id in Excel using macro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try what follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim dataRng As Range, dbRng As Range, helperRng As Range, cell As Range, found As Range

Set dbRng = Worksheets("DefectConsoliation1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion '<== check if it's your actual sheet name
Set dataRng = dbRng.Offset(1).Resize(dbRng.Rows.Count - 1)
Set helperRng = dbRng.Offset(dbRng.Rows.Count + 1, dbRng.Columns.Count + 1).Cells(1, 1)

dataRng.Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Copy Destination:=helperRng

With helperRng.CurrentRegion
    If .Rows.Count > 1 Then .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    For Each cell In .CurrentRegion
        Set found = dataRng.Columns(2).Find(what:=cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            dbRng.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=cell.Value
            found.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2) = Array(GetString(dataRng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), "duplicate")
            .AutoFilter
        End If
    Next cell
    .ClearContents
End With

End Sub

Function GetString(rng As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng
    GetString = GetString & cell.Value & ","
Next cell
If Len(GetString) > 0 Then GetString = Left(GetString, Len(GetString) - 1)

End Function
```

it makes use of a "helper" range, occupying one column only and starting from a cell two columns at the right and two rows below your data `CurrentRegion` (i.e. as per your data example, the "helper" range would be from cell F19 downwards). If you have relevant data in such localized data, you should change code accordingly

Comment: thanks a slot for trying,still unable to reach to my requirement. i have dded a new image screen shot of my final requirement. appreciate the help at the earliest.

Comment: Please upload an xls file.

Comment: i still dont have option to upload the excel as i am new to this, if i need to change the rows/cell? where should i mention that?

Comment: thanks for your valuable time .now its  just putting (,,,,,), below is the data. sorry i am unable to upload the excel sheet.

Comment: I couldn't test my last edited code since I'm not by PC. Try and descrive the actual range of your data and which columns hold relevant data and/or result

Comment: its working fine now, thanks a  lot, you are the best :)
i just changed to this code, and it worked

found.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 2) = Array(GetString(dataRng.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), "duplicate")

Comment: well there is plenty of resources in the web (just type something like "How to learn VBA") among which I found StackOverflow being one of the most valuable.

Comment: Sure will work towards that. 

i am facing one issue while running the above code on a huge data,any clue why? its says Run time error '1004, No cells were found.

Comment: well, you must add some more info: 1) which line does throw the error , 2) what's the structure of your data (for instance is it the same as per your last image attached), 3) UsedRange (which is the first row with at least a non blank cell, which is the first column with at least one non blank cell, which is the last row with at least one non blank cell, which is the last column with at least one non blank cell) ?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information.
- error comes on this line 
dataRng.Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Copy Destination:=helperRng

2.structure of data is same as attached, except column C(JiRA iD) which may be empty for some cells
3.Column A and B(LOB&Defect ID) will be always NON Empty for both first and last. 

-

Comment: Got it. But I'll be on it not sooner than in some 20 hours. In the meantime you may make attempts at adding /revising code to have it handle special cases. This will also be the most effective way of both understanding code and learning a piece of VBA

Comment: would it be possible to explain the above it a bit? so that i can make it up for my requirement. i am finding it very difficult to understand.:). i have huge requirement based on the above code.

Comment: As per your "structure", `dataRng.Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)` picks up column "Duplicate ID's"  cells with "constant" (i.e.; not resulting from formulas) text in it.  Should those text values ("CPMS-906", "CPMS-921",..) be some formula result and all other column cells not contain any "constant" text, than it would find no cells. If you want to consider text from formulas than: 1) change `xlCellTypeConstants` to `xlCellTypeFormulas` ) 2) remove `Destination:=helperRng` 3) add statement `helperRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. shouldn't it be `found.Offset(, 1)?.`

Comment: Ok, i am just trying to I am trying to get one thing here, 


    If G column (status) is Ready to Retest AND If Column D(Duplicate Status)="Duplicate" then take a value from Column C Duplicate id , and go to duplicate id row and hightlight it with color Green

am ok if its a separate function.. sorry for asking this :(.. i am able to make the logic, but struggling to put it as code...:(

Comment: Well it's no longer referrable to the current question so you may want to start a new one providing your coding efforts to have people here more helpful. Finally, my understanding is that my answer has proved useful to you. Should that be true you may want to up-vote it.

Comment: Ok will start a new thread. I am unable vote as it's requires 15 reputation... Sorry..